# Getting Random Crash connectAnimatedNodes: Animated node with tag (child) [3848] does not exist

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Getting this crash in few devices

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear if you are doing native development or anything else. Make sure you provide more details so the community can help you in a more efficient way. Check if this helps in any way, in case you are using React Native - github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33375

Comment: Please check the image attached